# Create html with javascript

Tags: javascript, class, html, rendering

I have here this code:

```
var photo = place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 50, 'maxHeight': 50 });
            var sideClick = jQuery("<a class=side_click href='#'></a>");
            $(sideClick).html(place.name+place.rating);
            $("#side_bar").append("<div class='elemenat'><div class='draggable'><img style='margin-left:3px; margin-top:5px;' src="+ photo +" width='46' height='42' /></div><div class='elementname'>").append(sideClick).append("</div></div>");
             $(sideClick).on("click", function() {
               markers[i].modalWindow_.getDetails(markers[i].place_);
             });
          }
```

and this code render:

```
<div id="side_bar">
       <div class="elemenat">
            <div class="draggable ui-draggable">
                  <img style="margin-left:3px; margin-top:5px;" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-T0_fJX5zza0/UdSnOaucZvI/AAAAAAAAAFc/gQhK3IbHJfY/w50-h50-s0/Small%2BLogo.png" width="46" height="42"></div>
             <div class="elementname"></div></div>

<a class="side_click" href="#">James Cook Hotel Grand Chancellor3.6</a>
```

How I must change js code to render html where     `<a class="side_click" href="#">James Cook Hotel Grand Chancellor3.6</a>` will be into `<div class="elementname"></div>` so

must be rendered like this:

```
<div class="elementname">
        <a class="side_click" href="#">James Cook Hotel Grand Chancellor3.6</a>
</div>
```

Comment: so how I can put sideClick into div class "elementname" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't create elements by raw HTML text**. Instead, **use jQuery's DOM manipulation capabilities**. It makes things much simpler to understand, maintain and less error-prone.

So instead of something like:

```
var sideClick = jQuery("<a class=side_click href='#'></a>");
$(sideClick).html(place.name + place.rating);
```

It is better to do:

```
var sideClick = $("<a>").addClass('side_click').attr('href', '#')
                        .text(place.name + place.rating);
```

Besides being easier to structure and spot errors, you also get the added benefit of **escaping** the `place.name + place.rating` string.

---

Check the updated code using this approach (and with the end result you expected):

```
var photo = place.photos[0].getUrl({
    'maxWidth': 50,
    'maxHeight': 50
});

var elemenatDiv = $('<div>').addClass('elemenat');
var draggableDiv = $('<div>').addClass('draggable');
var logo = $('<img>').css({'margin-left': '3px', 'margin-top': '5px'})
                     .attr('src', photo).attr('width', 46).attr('height', 42)
var sideClick = $("<a>").addClass('side_click').attr('href', '#')
                        .text(place.name + place.rating);
var elementnameDiv = $('<div>').addClass('elementname');

elemenatDiv.append(draggableDiv.append(logo));
elemenatDiv.append(elementnameDiv.append(sideClick));

$("#side_bar").append(elemenatDiv);

$(sideClick).on("click", function () {
    markers[i].modalWindow_.getDetails(markers[i].place_);
});
```

**[See demo fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/3SXKe/3/)**

Comment: <div class="elemenat"><div class="draggable ui-draggable"><img style="margin-left:3px; margin-top:5px;" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-J7a4ADPvF_o/T41m0NF0xgI/AAAAAAAPWSc/M556WwJ84Cw/w50-h50/Akaroa%2BCottages-%2BHeritage%2BBoutique%2BCollection" width="46" height="42"></div></div> code now render this

Answer (score 0):

Append sideclick to the elementname div, not to the `side_bar` div

```
var element = $("<div class='elemenat'><div class='draggable'><img style='margin-left:3px; margin-top:5px;' src="+ photo +" width='46' height='42' /></div>");

var elementName = $(<div class='elementname'>);

element.append(elementName);
elementName.append(sideclick);
$("#side_bar").append(element);
```

Comment: Do you understand what its doing? Or how its different than what your original code is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

You have a couple of different options. You could just change the order in which you append things, use the InsertAfter or InsertBefore methods, or my personal recommendation, putting everything onto the DOM and then using the wrap() function to wrap the side_click link with the div.

Something like

```
\\append everything
$('.side_click').wrap('<div class="elementname" />');
```